# Kotlin equivalent of some F# code matching on union type

Tags: kotlin, f#, arrow-kt

I'm learning Kotlin and am wondering if anyone out there could advise on what the following snippet of F# might look like in idiomatic Kotlin.

```
// a function that has an Option<int> as input
let printOption x = match x with
| Some i -> printfn "The int is %i" i
| None -> printfn "No value"
```

Thanks a million. (btw, the snippet is from Scott Wlaschin's wonderful [Domain Modeling Made Functional](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/books/))

Comment: in kotlin there is a [when expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression)

Comment: fun printOption(x: Int?) { if (x == null) print("No value") else print("The int is $i) }"

Comment: Apologies @SinneroftheSystem, I should have mentioned that I was aware of the when expression, but was trying to understand how close I could get to the F# version while writing idiomatic Kotlin.

Thanks @ChristianB. Is there a way to use a `val printOption` rather than a `fun`?

Comment: or use a when when you wanna match several cases: fun printOption(x: Int?) { when(x) { null -> { print("No Value") } 42 -> { print("1") } else -> print("value $x") } }

Comment: May be worth pointing out that Options are mostly a Java thing, and aren't much needed or used in Kotlin with its distinction between nullable and non-nullable types, and tools like the Elvis and safe-call operators to handle nulls safely.

Comment: On the other hand, nested `option`s (e.g. `int option option`) work in F#/OCaml/etc. but not with Kotlin nullable types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```kotlin
// as a function
fun printOption(x: Int?) {
  when(x) {
    null -> print("No Value")
    42 -> print("Value is 42")
    else -> print("Value is $x")
  } 
}
```

```kotlin
// as a functional type stored in printOption
val printOption: (Int?) -> Unit = { x ->
  when(x) {
    null -> print("No Value")
    42 -> print("Value is 42")
    else -> print("Value is $x")
  } 
}
```

You can pass this function type like any other variable and call it like:

```kotlin
printOption(42)
// or
printOption.invoke(42)
```

**Documentation**

- [Higher-Order Functions and Lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)
- [Kotlin | Function Type, Lambda and Higher-Order Functions](https://hmkcode.com/kotlin/kotlin-function-type-lambda/)

Comment: That's fantastic @ChristianB - exactly what I was grappling with. Thank you!